# Google Sheets Query - fill zeros for dates when no data was recorded

Tags: sql, google-sheets

How do I change my query in this google sheet so that it generates a table that has a column for every week, even if there is no data for that week? (display 0 in the values fields)

The problem I'm running into is that if there is a week or date with no data, it's not listed. I would like to generate a row/column with 0 for dates without data.

This is how the query is currently written:

```
=QUERY(A3:D9,"Select A, sum(C) group by A pivot D")
```

Here's the sheet (hyperlinked so you can see it):

[image: The google sheet]

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem you need to solve is to know which data pieces are missing. Do you need the entries for every single day in a given date range? Only weekdays? Only weekdays, except public holidays? etc.

Once you know that, you can insert the missing data in the query itself, by concatenating the source table with literal data as below (where I'm manually adding a combination of Red with Nov 5), or with another query/resultset of another formula that gives you the missing data:

```
=QUERY({A3:D9; {"Red", date(2018,11,5), 0, weeknum(date(2018,11,5))}},
       "Select Col1, sum(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col4")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ttarchala. What I want is something more dynamic. I'd like to be able to refresh this query and get all weeks/dates from StartDate to EndDate without needing to go into the query and add each date specifically. The idea is that I can run the query to see sales by week and that it would return every week (or date) and the units sold in that week. In the weeks where there are no sales, I want it to explicitly return "0" instead of just skipping the week.